# How can I run if condition inside this function

Tags: javascript

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("div"),
    myInput = document.getElementById("input"),
    theAges = document.getElementById("ages");

//Element.event = function () {// code}

theAges.onchange = function() {
  "use strict";

  myDiv.innerHTML = myInput.value * theAges.value;

  if (myInput.value === isNaN()) {
    myDiv.innerHTML = "this is not a number";
  }
};
```

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
if (isNaN(myInput.value))
```

isNaN is a function that take in parameter the value you want to test and return a boolean.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN